# Does polarisation matter in double slit experiment?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, double-slit-experiment

So I am studying diffraction, in particular the diffraction of electromagnetic waves using a double slit set up. However, there seems to be no mention of the polarisation of electromagnetic waves and I wondered would the experiment differ if the polarisation was different?

I also have the same question regrading the following set up using a conducting plate. Surely polarisation would result in a differing pattern of interference?

[image: diffraction image]

Comment: No difference at all.

Comment: @JonCuster What about if I use a conducting plate to carry out diffraction as demonstrated in the edited question. Wouldn't polarisation result in differing propagation through the plate resulting in different diffraction patterns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polarisation can matter in real two slit experiments. If metal is used for the slit then the boundary conditions are different for perpendicular and parallel polarization. The difference becomes important when the slit width and separation are comparable to the wavelength, so for large diffraction angles.

Comment: Polarization can also matter regardless of the slit material, if the slits are very small so the beams spread widely, and the slits are relatively far apart.  In that case, the two beams will approach each other at  a wide angle.  Linearly polarized in the direction of the slits, interference will be the same as the simple analysis would indicate.  Linearly polarized perpendicular to the slits, there will be no interference when the beams approach at 90 degrees to each other.  Bottom line: polarization makes a difference in the near-field, not in the far-field.

Comment: @S.McGrew You are absolutely correct. Usually interference patterns are observed in the far field limit but in image formation lithography or microscopy this is very relevant.